# emacs ido-ignore-directories and files don't ignore the all list

Tags: emacs, ido

I'm trying to ignore cmake generated files and directories and `.`, `..` in Emacs `ido`.

This is my Emacs config:

```
(setq ido-show-dot-for-dired nil)
(setq ido-ignore-directories '("CMakeFiles/" ".git/" ".bin/" "Testing/" "tmp/"))
(setq ido-ignore-files '("\.cmake" "CMakeCache.txt"))
```

It hides `.git`, `*.cmake` and `CMakeCache.txt`, but it still suggests `Testing`, `..`, `.` and `CMakeFiles` in auto-completion.

Comment: what `ido` function are you calling?  `ido-ignore-directories` should affect the `ido-dired-*` whereas `ido-ignore-files` affects others like `ido-find-file` -- I don't *think* they are both used in either case

Comment: @picklerick I'm calling by `C-x C-f`.

Comment: I assume that is bound to `ido-find-file` (at least it is for me), so you should be able to just add "Testing", etc. to `ido-ignore-files`

Comment: @picklerick Thank you so much! it works! also would you please let me know how can I add `.` and `..` in the ignore list?

Comment: @picklerick Thank you so much! I've also put the default values and now it ignores `.` and `..` paths. Would you please put your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of those variables, it is not abundantly clear (to me anyway) how they work/which functions they affect, so I share your confusion.

For the function in question, `ido-find-file` per comments, modifying the `ido-ignore-files` variable to include the unwanted directories should be sufficient.

After a little further investigation -- tracing the ido library and calling `ido-find-file` -- I can say with uncertainty that `ido-ignore-directories` is not directly relevant here, the (shortened) code path being

`ido-find-file` -> ... -> `ido-make-file-list` -> ... -> `ido-file-name-all-completions`